# Spanish Grammar Checking in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, language

Is there a way to add the proofing materials necessary for microsoft word 2011 for macs to check grammar in spanish without reinstalling microsoft word?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is impossible since grammar check for the Spanish language for Word for Mac 2011 is not available. The latest version of Word for Mac 2016 however has the desired functionality.

Here is the grammar check feature in action: 
[Word for Mac 2016](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CKzK.gif)

Microsoft Word for Mac developed in a very different path from Word (and indeed Office) for Windows, and so you do not have the feature parity that you might expect from a product of the same name. There is no way that you can get grammar check of any kind for Spanish in Word for Mac 2011.

You can see from this link that it is not available: 
[Microsoft Word for Mac 2011 Language features](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Proofing-tools-that-are-available-for-each-language-12ad07e8-30eb-4aa4-82b1-48e339efef08)

Answer (score 0):

#### Is there a way to add the proofing materials necessary check grammar in Spanish?

The proofing tools should already be installed. If they are not see the instructions below.

---

#### Proofing tools that are available for each language

> When you type text in an Office application, Office uses proofing
>   tools to check the document. Depending on which Office application you
>   are using, proofing tools can check spelling or grammar, hyphenate
>   text, and look up words in the thesaurus.
>
> You can switch between proofing tools by selecting a different
>   language for your document. To learn how to select a different
>   language, see [Check spelling and grammar in a different language](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Check-spelling-and-grammar-in-a-different-language-b872cb8a-7568-4512-9c8e-1da7ed5176ec).
>
> When you use the keyboard layout for a language that comes with
>   proofing tools, you can also use the proofing tools for that language.
>   For example, if you change the keyboard layout in Word from English to
>   German, Word automatically begins using the German dictionary, the
>   German AutoCorrect list, and the German grammar checker. The German
>   thesaurus appears in the Reference Tools panel.
>
> The English (U.S.) version of Office for Mac 2011 comes with proofing
>   tools for the following languages:
>
> ```
> Language Proofing tools 
>
> ...
>
> Spanish  Spelling, thesaurus, hyphenation 
>
> ...
> ```
>
> Proofing tools for these languages are installed in
>   /Applications/Microsoft Office 2011/Office/Shared
>   Applications/Proofing Tools/.
>
> **If the proofing tool that you want is not installed, use the Office
>   Installer on your original installation disk to perform a custom
>   installation and select only the check boxes for the proofing tools
>   that you want.**

Source [Proofing tools that are available for each language](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Proofing-tools-that-are-available-for-each-language-12ad07e8-30eb-4aa4-82b1-48e339efef08#bmwd)

Comment: Does grammar checking come with later versions of ms word?

Comment: @user3163829 I haven't checked every version, but for Word 2016 you need to install the Proofing Tools yourself, they are part of the [Language Accessory Pack for Office 2016](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Language-Accessory-Pack-for-Office-2016-82ee1236-0f9a-45ee-9c72-05b026ee809f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)